# Firestore, Check which fields has been changed during valueChanges()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hey is there any way to check which property has been changed during valueChanges() execution?

I have a document like this:

```
{
  player1Online: false,
  player2Online: false,
  player1Score: false,
  ...
  ...

}
```

I want to execute certain function on score changes. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK will not indicate which specific properties or values changed since the last snapshot.  You will have to diff them yourself somehow.